ModuleNotFoundError with playsound in Python virtual environment despite package installation
I'm facing a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import the playsound library in my Python script, even though the library is installed in my virtual environment.
"I initially tested the playsound library outside of the virtual environment, where it worked successfully with both versions 1.2.2 and 1.3.0. However, when I switched to the virtual environment, I consistently encountered the error: No module named 'playsound'.
To resolve the issue, I attempted various troubleshooting methods such as removing and reinstalling the library, switching between different versions of the library, and experimenting with different import statements. I also attempted to locate the playsound library in the Lib/site-packages directory, but it was not present there.
Despite these efforts, when I run pip list, the playsound library appears as installed. Yet, when I execute my script, I continue to encounter the error: No module named 'playsound'.
Here is my code:
from playsound import playsound

# # Play assistant sound
# def playAssistantSound():
playsound("\www\\assets\\audio\\start_sound.mp3")


If it’s showing up with pip list you can try run ‘pip show playsound’. This should show the location where playsound is installed which should be within your venv.

If you still have this issue, please provide more information about your setup. Create a fresh venv, freshly install playsound etc. and share your results so that they are reproducible for others. With the information you have provided so far it is hard to tell what is going on.

I used the command pip show playsound to verify the installation of the library, and it confirmed that the library was installed within the virtual environment. However, I am still experiencing issues with its functionality. I suspect the problem might be related to GitHub, as I created a new virtual environment and repeated the installation process, which worked flawlessly without any issues.
